# Codeigniter Project Not Working on localhost

Tags: codeigniter, localhost

I want to run the codeigniter project which I am currently working on in localhost I setup each and everythng accordingly

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/site';

$config['index_page'] = '';
```

its works fine in my office but when i bought it home to work more on off days I started getting errors it only shows the home or index page and when i navigate to other pages it displays 404 object not found 
just displays the home page all the other routes not working 
please help

Comment: This may be bocause of  the htaccess file is missing

Answer (score 0):

Reasons can be

1. You might have copied the code in different CodeIgniter version.
   Some code standard differs from version to version.
2. Might be because of database.

Comment: The answer seems incomplete, please add more details

Answer (score 0):

Create .htaccess file and put below code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```